# Finding $\mathbb{E}\left(g \left(\min(X,c) \right)\right)$, where $g(X) \sim\exp(1)$ and $c$ : constant.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Define $Y = \min(X, c)$, for a given constant $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$, and nonzero real-valued random variable $X \sim F_X$, $F_X$ the cdf of $X$. I'm trying to find $\mathbb{E} \left(g(Y)\right)$, where $g(X) \sim \exp(1)$.

---

**My attempt**

First I have to find the distribution of $Y$. Since

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_Y(y) &= f_X(y | X > c)P(X > c)  + P(y = c | X \le c) P(X \le c)
\end{aligned}
$$

thus

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} \left(g(Y)\right) &= \int_\mathbb{R} g(y) f_Y(y) dy \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} g(x) f_Y(x) dx \\
&= \int_{0}^c \exp(-x) F_X(c)dx + \int_c^{\infty} \exp(-x)f_X(x)(1-F_X(c))dx
\end{aligned}
$$

But I think I'm lost. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E(g(Y)) =P(X\leq c) E(g(Y)|X\leq c) +  P(X>c) E(g(Y)|X > c) =F(c) \cdot 1+(1-F(c) \cdot c.$$
Because when $X\leq c$ the mean of $g(Y)$ is an expontential cause $Y =X$ as the minimum of $X$ and $c$ and in the other cause the expected value of $c$ is $c$.

Comment: But $\mathbb{E} [ g(X) | X \le c ] \neq 1 $. It's $\int_0^c \frac{x e^{-x}}{F(c)}$

Comment: But you are interested for $E(g(Y)|X\leq c)=E(g(X))=1$ because g(X)~Exp(1).

Comment: $g(Y) | X \le c \overset{d}{\equiv} g(X) | X \le c$, but not same with $g(X)$

Comment: Yes, you are correct, sorry for misleading you. You have to find $E(g(Y)|X \leq c)$$=\int_{0}^{c}\frac{xe^{-x}}{F(c)}$ and replace 1 in my solution.